# Converting class library dll file to executable file

Tags: exe, class-library

I'm having a InstallerDLL class library. When i build the file I'll get a InstallerDLL.dll in /bin folder. But now I need to get an InstallerDLL.exe file for the same class library file while building.

I tried by creating a windows application InstallerEXE and added the InstallerDLL.dll file in the reference. I have got InstallerEXE.exe file in /bin folder. But how can I access all the functions and methods of the class library by running the InstallerEXE.exe file?

Anyone please help me out from this.

Thanks,
Naren.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what code is there in your dll. Normally development tools like visual studio, allow you to see all the classess which are in your dll.using a proper IDE, you will be able to figure out the api, exposed in that dll and then you can use it